# Keep a 2-tuple of ints within a specific range

Tags: python, if-statement

I am having trouble with logic checks. There is a coordinate system grid that is 15x15, row x column.

There is a random list of 2-tuples that contains coordinates:`[(3,3),(4,5),(14,14),(13,0),(0,13)]`. (r, c)

I would like to check if some random choice tuple is within a certain range: 2x2 and 12x12. So for example the tuple: (3,3) and (4,5) would be allowed, but (13,0) and (0, 13) would not.

How would I go about implementing checks to see if a tuple pair lies within the range?

Comment: Check that each of the two elements in the tuple lies between 2 and 12? Am I missing something?

Comment: Since I randomly pick a tuple from the list, I have tried `if (randOption[0] > 12 or randOption[0] < 5) and 
 (randOption[1] > 12 or randOption[1] < 5):` and switching around 'and' and 'or' to whatever seems to make sense at the time.

Comment: `2 <= r <= 12 >= c >= 2`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best approach would be to not create random tuples outside the wanted range at all:

```
import random

def randCoord(xMin,xMax,yMin,yMax, numCoords):
    """Generates 'numCoords' random coord tuples between ([xMin,xMax],[yMin,yMax])""" 
    for _ in range(numCoords):
        yield (random.randint(xMin,xMax),random.randint(yMin,yMax)) 

test = randCoord(2,13,2,13,5)  # all will be valid
```

---

If the creation of the random tuple is out of your hand, you should go for logic check (see [Louis Sugys answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48967314/7505395) ). For a small sample areas a look up table (LUT) is a viable option:

Your area is very limited - 15*15 = 225 elements total of which only 100 are ok- if you want to repeatedly check it by lookup, create a set with all allowed ones and look them up.

As pointed out by the comments to my answer: for bigger problem sizes you should probably not use a lookup - for this problem it might be ok to use a LUT:

```
allowed = set((x,y) for x in range(2,13) for y in range (2,13))

test = [(2,5),(7,13)]
for t in test:
    print(t, "Yes" if t in allowed else "No")
```

and test them. Done.

Output:

```
(2, 5) Yes
(7, 13) No
```

---

If in doubt, measure (trice - cut once): Just got curious about timings and if a GeneratedLUT would outperform the once created set (which I correctly doubted) and *how bad* a LUT would be compared to logical checks:

Edit: fixed several errors due to tips from @StefanPochmann in the comments

```
import timeit

setupTxt = """import random 
random.seed(42)

def randCoord(xMin,xMax,yMin,yMax, numCoords):
    for _ in range(numCoords):
        yield (random.randint(xMin,xMax),random.randint(yMin,yMax)) 

def allowed(xMin,xMax,yMin,yMax):
    from itertools import product
    return product( range(xMin,xMax+1) , range (yMin,yMax+1))

allowedLUT = set( ((x,y) for x in range(2,13) for y in range (2,13)))

# need list(generator) so data persists between iterations
testSample = list(randCoord(0,15,0,15,1000)) 
"""
n = 500
```

Tests:

```
# LUT-set prefilled and checked
LUTtiming = timeit.timeit(
    "for t in testSample: 1 if t in allowedLUT else -1", 
    setup = setupTxt, number=n)

# LUTgenerated on each call
LUTgenerated = timeit.timeit(
    "for t in testSample: 1 if t in allowed(2,12,2,12) else -1", 
    setup = setupTxt, number=n)

# simple condition checking
condCheckTiming= timeit.timeit(
    "for x,y in testSample: 1 if 2 <= x <= 12 and 2 <= y <= 12 else -1", 
    setup = setupTxt, number=n)

print ("LUT:   \t{0:f}\nLUTGen:\t{1:f}\nConds: \t{2:f}".format(LUTtiming, 
                                                               LUTgenerated, 
                                                               condCheckTiming))
```

Outputs (Laptop - pyfiddle.io gives odd numbers):

```
LUT:    0.753209  # faster then conditional checking but takes memory for LUT
LUTGen: 8.983708  # generator not suited for _this_ purpose
Conds:  0.828372  # less memory as LUT, 10% slower
```

Comment: That is one way around the barn.

Comment: Perhaps not a hugely scalable solution. allowed could get very big very quickly with an increase in grid size.

Comment: @LouisSugy look at the demo data provided in the Q.

Comment: @PatrickArtner Even if that's the case, the solution is not scalable, and takes more time and memory than just checking the condition.

Comment: Surely it's far easier just to check the limits of the coords rather than just check if it's contained a in an object containing all possible permitted coords

Comment: @KindStranger thanks for the input - the Q talks about 15*15 of which 10*10 are acceptable - neither memory consumption nor other data types are of concern here. LuisSugy's solution provides the "check coords" - this is an alternative approach, but not suited to bigger areas. Noted it down inthe answer as caveat.

Comment: @StephenRauch well the straight one through the door was taken by Louis Sugy answer already - so had to take it through the roof latch instead

Comment: @StefanPochmann quite a blunder. Did not think that `timeit` would mess with the testdatagenerator. Also fixed the list to set error and shortened the code to use the same setup overall. Thanks a buch for putting my nose into my errors.

Comment: Much better now :-). I'd still get rid of the extra `i` stuff, though, and just put the check in the loop. Like `for t in testSample: t in allowedLUT`. And for the "cond" solution it would be better to use normal Python code, i.e., unpack the coordinates in the loop and use chained comparisons: `for r, c in testSample: 2 <= r <= 12 and 2 <= c <= 12`. I mean, better measure code that people would actually use, not code that some newbie made up :-P

Answer (score 1):

Let's say that your list of coordinates is called `coords`. Then, to verify that the i-th element is ok, you just use the expression:

```
coords[i][0] >= 2 and coords[i][1] >= 2 and coords[i][0] <= 12 and coords[i][1] <= 12
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach if you want to work with, given the lower and upper bounds, would be to create two ranges for X and Y axis and check for every coordinate if it's within these boundaries:

```
#Input
coord = [(3,3),(4,5),(14,14),(13,0),(0,13)]
lowerBorder = (2,2)
upperBorder = (12,12)

# Create the ranges for each axis.
xRange, yRange = [range(lowerBorder[i], upperBorder[i]) for i in range(2)]

# Filter the coordinates.
valid = list(filter(lambda c: c[0] in xRange and c[1] in yRange, coord))

print(valid)
```

Output:

```
[(3, 3), (4, 5)]
```